# Code for fetching the corresponding images from classes(e.g 1-SHIRTS, 2-SHOES etc) of objects using matplotlib.pylot.imshow()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

As shown below my model is getting trained on only 1500 images(excluding 0.2 validation_data), but my FASHION_MNIST train data has 60000 images. Can anyone help? 
Modified Question: Need Code for fetching the corresponding  images from classes of objects (e.g 1-SHIRTS, 2-SHOES etc) using matplotlib.pylot.imshow()

I am using google colab notebook

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels),(test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images/255.0
test_images = test_images/255.0

train_images = train_images.reshape(len(train_images),28,28,1)
test_images = test_images.reshape(len(test_images),28,28,1)

K = len(set(train_labels))
train_images.shape

i = Input(shape=train_images[0].shape)
x = Conv2D(32, (3,3),strides=2, activation='relu')(i)
x = Conv2D(64, (3,3),strides=2, activation='relu')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x= Dense(K, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(i,x)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
r = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2)

Epoch 1/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4759 - accuracy: 0.8301 - val_loss: 0.3751 - val_accuracy: 0.8647
Epoch 2/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.3243 - accuracy: 0.8812 - val_loss: 0.3257 - val_accuracy: 0.8793
Epoch 3/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.2759 - accuracy: 0.8974 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.8982
Epoch 4/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.2426 - accuracy: 0.9094 - val_loss: 0.2796 - val_accuracy: 0.8934
Epoch 5/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.2136 - accuracy: 0.9209 - val_loss: 0.2730 - val_accuracy: 0.9007
Epoch 6/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.1902 - accuracy: 0.9286 - val_loss: 0.2614 - val_accuracy: 0.9039
Epoch 7/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.1672 - accuracy: 0.9378 - val_loss: 0.2660 - val_accuracy: 0.9063
Epoch 8/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.1451 - accuracy: 0.9467 - val_loss: 0.2773 - val_accuracy: 0.9082
Epoch 9/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.1279 - accuracy: 0.9526 - val_loss: 0.2956 - val_accuracy: 0.9013
Epoch 10/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.1121 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.3099 - val_accuracy: 0.9034
```

Please help in above

Comment: help in what? clarify.

Comment: Thanks Zabir. Got that one. however you may help with this code.I am trying to fetch image given the label using matplotlib. e.g. I know my image class/label is 'SHIRTS' . what is the code to fetch corresponding image using label name or label index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras [model.fit](https://keras.io/models/model/) receive as argument *batch size* and *steps_per_epoch*.
*Batch size* define the number of samples that model "looks at" before updates weights.
*Steps_per_epoch* define *"number of steps (batches of samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch"*.

*Batch size*, if not specifyied, is by default set to 32. That's why the number "1500" appears on your train. Considering your validation split, you have 48k images for train, that divided by 32 generate 1500 *steps*. Relax, your model is looking for all your train images!

If you want to see 48k there, you can try

```
r = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=1, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
 4013/48000 [=>............................] - ETA: 1:28 - loss: 0.7459 - accuracy: 0.7207
```

For you can plot your train images fetching by class you can do

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

interesting_class = 0
index = np.where(train_labels == interesting_class)
plt.imshow(train_images[index[0][0]], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
```

You can also do `index[0][N]` to get N'th image of `interesting_class`.

Comment: Could you please also help me in code, I trying to fetch image given the label using matplotlib. e.g. I know my image class/label is 'SHIRTS' . what is the code to fetch corresponding image using label name or label index.

Comment: The best way to do this is transforming your label to one-hot-encoding. Check this out [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/categorical-encoding-using-label-encoding-and-one-hot-encoder-911ef77fb5bd).
Convert each class into a number, then turn it into vector of ones and zeros.

Comment: I got your point but my question is lets say my labels are already encoded e.g. 1 for SHIRTS, 2 for Trousers, 3 for SHOE etc. Using the label number (1 for SHIRT) how can I fetch corresponding image for each label class (i.e 1, 2, 3 etc)using matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(). Hope you are got my question

Comment: I will edit my answer to add this, if you can edit your question too it will be very nice to help other users.

Comment: Augusto Maillo  I have edited my question. Pl do the needful. Thanks

Comment: tried the above code provided for fashion_mnist dataset, but it is giving error